# How to know if all the messages are consumed in kafka-spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

We are triggering a Kafka consumer on a conditional basis. How to know if all the messages of the topic are consumed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` `@Bean` to configure the `idleEventInterval` on the listener container(s) and use an `@EventListener` method to consume the container idle events.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_advanced_consumer_configuration