# Pause message consumption from main kafka stream and start from other kafka topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using @StreamListener (spring cloud stream) to consume messages from a topic (*input-channel*), do some processing and save into some cache or database.

My requirement is, if DB goes down while processing the consumed message, I want to pause the main consumer(input-channel), and start consuming from another TOPIC (INPUT56-CHANNEL), and as soon as It consume all the message (doesn't have many) from INPUT56-CHANNEL, I want to resume the main consumer (input-channel) again.

Can that be achieved??

Comment: You can probably make this happen with Spring Integration, but I don't think that Stream has complex enough routing to do the switch-off you're talking about. (FWIW, it sounds like you're attempting a variation of the _circuit-breaker_ pattern.)

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control to control the binding lifecycle - and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722291/how-to-know-if-all-the-messages-are-consumed-in-kafka-spring-cloud-stream/69723619#69723619) for how to detect when all the secondary records have been consumed.

Comment: Thanks Gary, will try

Comment: HI @GaryRussell Can you share any example, I am confused in 2 things 1st, how the secondary consumer will know that it needs to start consuming now after db is down (maybe I can use some toggle or something), 
2nd, After the secondary consumer finish consuming, how the primary consumer will know, it finished and resume again.
for pausing and resuming I am using "BindingsEndpoint". That works fine.

Comment: Set the secondaty binding to `autostartup: false`; when you pause the primary binding, start the secondary binding; when you receive an idle event (or all idle events if using concurrency), stop the secondary binding and resume the primary.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have one more doubt, How do I start secondary binding programatically from primary binding in spring-cloud-stream (since after pausing this I want to start that). At start, I can set this property 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-channel.consumer.auto-startup' false 

Another question,  the  idle events of secondary binding should be known to primary binding so that I can resume it but I don't think we can use '@EventListener' and '@StreamListener' on the same function??. I just can't picture everything together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@StreamListener` is deprecated; you should convert to the functional programming model instead.

Here is an example using that model (but the same techniques apply to the deprecated listeners).

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=input1;input2

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input1-in-0.group=grp1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2-in-0.consumer.auto-startup=false
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2-in-0.group=grp2

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input2-in-0.consumer.idle-event-interval=5000
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So69726610Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So69726610Application.class, args);
    }

    boolean dbIsDown = true;

    @Autowired
    BindingsLifecycleController controller;

    TaskExecutor exec = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> input1() {
        return str -> {
            System.out.println(str);
            if (this.dbIsDown) {
                this.controller.changeState("input1-in-0", State.PAUSED);
                this.controller.changeState("input2-in-0", State.STARTED);
                throw new RuntimeException("Paused");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> input2() {
        return System.out::println;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void idle(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        // assumes concurrency = 1 (default)
        if (event.getListenerId().contains("input2-in-0")) {
            this.controller.changeState("input1-in-0", State.RESUMED);
            this.exec.execute(() -> this.controller.changeState("input2-in-0", State.STOPPED));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gary , this is just what I needed. I'll test it.

Comment: Hi Gary...I have a question, In my application, both the topics are in same group, It rebalances the group every time  when I start/stop the secondary binding programatically, Can we avoid this rebalance anyhow??

Comment: It is not good practice to put both listeners in the same group, for exactly that reason.

Comment: Gary, have one more doubt, When I pause the consumer, can I discard the  current message without processing  and consume it again when I resume, though I use autoCommit

Comment: Yes, throwing an exception (with the default `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`) will cause the record to be redelivered after the container is resumed.

Comment: Hi Gary, I throw an exception after these statements for current message this.controller.changeState("input1-in-0", State.PAUSED);
this.controller.changeState("input2-in-0", State.STARTED);  but it does't redeliver the message when the consumer is Resumed, but when I restart the application it redeliver all the messages which got exception, Is there any property to set or something??

Comment: See the application in my answer. When I added a record to the topic, it kept cycling the two containers over and over again. If you are seeing a different result you have done something wrong. Debug logging should help you.

Comment: Quick question regarding pause and resume. What is the core difference between pause and resume and stop and start? When should I use what?

Comment: pause keeps the consumer active, stop closes the consumer. If you have multiple instances of your application, with pause, this instance keeps the partition assignment; with stop, a rebalance occurs and the partitions are assigned to another instance.